# Cannot select ListViewItem because a rectangle is in the way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection and when items are added to the ListView, if you hover over a ListViewItem, you will see that not only the ListViewItem itself if highlighted, but there is also another slightly-smaller, darker-blue rectangle that appears. Now this slightly smaller rectangle prevents you from being able to select the ListViewItem because it is on-top of the ListViewItem.

Why is it there and how do I get rid of it?

```
<Grid Margin="0, 25, 0, 22" Grid.Column="0">
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a ListViewItem in your ListViewItem. The ListView will automatically wrap it's items in a container so you don't have to do that. Remove the ListViewItem from your DataTemplate.

Comment: There is a similiar issue with MenuItems that is a much bigger pain to get around :(

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ListviewItem` from `DataTemplate`. `ListView` will wrap whatever is in your `DataTemplate` in `ListViewItem`. If you have something to set against `ListViewItem` do it through `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```